# Meaning of critical acclaim

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning

**The voluntary work that we have done to clean our locality received critical acclaim.**

Is it a correct sentence? I am a non native English speaker so I have a confusion of using critical acclaim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably wondering how something can be *critical* (which is often perceived as negative) but also give acclaim (which is positive).

"*Critical acclaim*" means something received positive reviews or praise from *professional critics*.

It can be quite an important distinction to make because sometimes there is a difference of opinion between critics and the general public. For example, a movie might receive terrible reviews from professional critics yet be warmly received and enjoyed by the public, or vice versa.

For example:

- The film received critical acclaim but a lukewarm box-office response.
- The film was panned by critics but beloved by fans.

---

It does seem unusual that there is critical claim for 'voluntary work' as in your example - I suspect the term has been misused slightly and probably refers to some kind of 'official' recognition, such as an awards scheme or the like.